# How to read incoming SMS in a ReactNative app when app is not running?

Tags: react-native, sms

There are several ReactNative SMS plugins available but most read SMS when app is in foreground. How can I read SMS when app is not even running, like a native SMS reader app?

Comment: Did you find any solution on how to do this? @Shatiz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any libraries available. But you can do as follows-

1. Create a BackgroundScanService.java which is an android service, which keeps scanning the incoming sms, when it receives any sms. It broadcasts the sms.
2. Create BackgroundScanModule.java, this file is the interface between your react native and Java code. Once sms is received in the broadcast receiver it passes that data to headless js. Headless js performs task when app is in the background and it performs action defined by user even when app is killed. For more info on Headless JS check https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android

I had implemented similar service for beacon scanning, you can check it here - https://medium.com/@skytreasure/react-native-beacon-scanner-when-app-is-not-running-android-172077644bc0

Comment: Hi, is it possible to do the same on ios?

Comment: @kd12345 No not possible in iOS